# Msal.js: node_modules/msal/lib-commonjs/index has no exported member 'User'

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to [use Msal.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js) version 0.1.3 in an Angular app and I'm receiving the following error:

> ERROR in C:/Users/blah/source/repos/myapp/src/app/shared/authentication.service.ts (63,28): Namespace '"C:/Users/blah/source/repos/myapp/node_modules/msal/lib-commonjs/index"' has no exported member 'User'.
>
> webpack: Failed to compile.

What am I doing wrong?

---

I'm importing Msal into my `AuthenticationService` via `import * as Msal from 'msal';` if that helps at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preface: I also had `import { User } from 'msal/lib-commonjs/User';`.

---

On line 63, I had: `public getUser(): Msal.User { ... }`.  I needed to have `public getUser(): User { ... }` as `User` is not defined in `msal` as the error stated!

Lesson learned, look at the line number in the build errors!

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between

```
import A from '/src/A'
```

and

```
import { A } from '/src/A'
```

Which imports the script from the file exports. If you look at the exports, you can see these two different corresponding formats

```
export default A = ...
```

and

```
export A = ...
```